# Undefined for multi-row query for react-native-sqlite-storage

Tags: sqlite, react-native

Currently, I am attempting to use react-native-sqlite-storage in my React Native application.  I am very new to React Native & Javascript as a whole, but was shifted to frontend to try to shift our use of client-side JSONs into a client-side SQLite database.

After some digging on Stack Overflow, the closest thing I could find to my problem was ([react native react-native-sqlite-storage not return result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51475821/react-native-react-native-sqlite-storage-not-return-result)).

However, after attempting the callback , I am still receiving undefined for my

Here is my callback function:

```
nextPackage (q_id: number, callback) {
    let pack = [];
    db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT * FROM Questions INNER JOIN Choices on Choices.q_id = Questions.global_id WHERE Questions.global_id = ?',
            [q_id],
            (tx, results) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    console.log('row:', results.rows.item(i));
                    this.pack.push(results.rows.item(i));
                }
                console.log('packCheck:' + this.pack);
                callback(return this.pack);
            }, function (tx, error) {
                console.log('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

And the screen that calls it:

```
this.wrapper = new SurveyController(this.session.data_next.algorithm);
    console.log('next qID: ' + this.session.data_next.qID);
    this.pack = this.wrapper.nextPackage(this.session.data_next.qID, console.log(this.pack));
```

Running the application however shows that this.pack is still undefined after running it.

My apologies if the problem is rudimentary, but I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Instead of `this.pack.push` u might need to write `pack.push` since you have declared `pack` as block variable. I am not sure why you have given `callback( return this.pack)`, instead it will be just `callback(pack)`. Lastly, while calling `nextPackage`, in the second argument, you have called `console.log(this.pack)`, this will print `undefined` since `nextPackage` has not called yet, try this `...nextPackage(this.session.data_next.qID, console.log)`.